# Block specific value from ini_get function

Tags: php, function, ini

I want to block `ini_get` function for `auto_prepend_file` value.
I don't want to block the function by `disable_functions` option, just for specific value.
There is any way to do it?

Comment: AFAIK, it is impossible without patching the PHP source.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov What do you mean?

Comment: I mean changing the source code of PHP and compiling your own version.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov I update every version of PHP, so it not the solution for me.

Comment: Ah, it is possible with uopz extension. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install [`uopz`](https://github.com/krakjoe/uopz) extension, then create `mod_ini_get.php` file as follows:

```
<?php
uopz_set_return('ini_get', function ($k) {
  if ($k === 'auto_prepend_file')
    return var_export(ini_get($k), true) . " - modified";
  return ini_get($k);
}, true);
```

Modify the `auto_prepend_file` INI option:

```
auto_prepend_file=mod_ini_get.php
```

Test it:

```
var_dump(ini_get('auto_prepend_file'));
var_dump(ini_get('engine'));
```

Sample output:

```
string(28) "'mod_ini_get.php' - modified"
bool(false)
```